# Azure deployment not finding any files to deploy

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I have configured two on-premises deployments of our ASP.NET Web API services. One to our staging server and one to our production server. Both are deployed without any problems.

I've recently begun investigating how to deploy these services to Azure as we'd like to make more use of cloud services going forwards. So I've setup a deployment to the Azure account I created as in the screenshot.

[image]

It connects to the Azure account but then fails stating that it cannot find any files to deploy as in the screenshot below.

[image]

When I look in the folder the files are definitely there. They are the same files that were deployed to the staging and production endpoints.

I can't understand why the Azure deployment fails to find these files, yet our on-premises deployments do.

Comment: Did you set up a build step prior to a deploy step using the vsts build and deploy capabilities?

Comment: Yes I have a full CI / CD pipeline setup on TFS 2015. This builds the solution prior to any release / deploy taking place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could deploy web app to Azure app service on my side, here is the detailed steps, you could refer to it.

**Build definition**

[image]

**NuGet Installer**

[image]

**Visual Studio Build**

[image]

Note : you could find *PackageLocation* ($(build.artifactstagingdirectory)) from *MSBuild Arguments*

**Azure App Service Deploy**

[image]

Note: specify *Package or Folder* based on the value of *PackageLocation* you find from *MSBuild Arguments*

Comment: I was pointing to the wrong location on my deployment step. For deployments to on-premises servers you need to specify the published build articles. For deployment to Azure it's the package zip file you need to specify. Your screenshot made this distinction clear. I've now got a successful deployment to Azure :)